# finding $x$ out of $nx^{n-1}-2nx^{2n-1}=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $$nx^{n-1}-2nx^{2n-1}=0$$

$$nx^{n-1}=2nx^{2n-1}$$

$$e^{ln(nx^{n-1})}=e^{ln(2x^{2n-1})}$$

$$e^{(n-1)\cdot ln(nx)}=e^{(2n-1)\cdot ln(2x)}$$

$$(n-1)\cdot ln(nx)=
(2n-1)\cdot ln(2x)$$

How should I continue? the result is $x=2^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Comment: You can cut the logarithm : $ln(nx) = ln(n) + ln(x)$ and $ln(2x) = ln(2) + ln(x)$. Also maybe an easier way would have been to first divide your equation by $nx^{n-1}$ and get $1 -2x^n = 0$. (Assuming $n \neq 0, x \neq 0$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler approach:
$$nx^{n-1}-2nx^{2n-1}=0\Leftrightarrow nx^{n-1}(1-2x^{n})=0.$$
So it suffices to solve $x^n=0$ which yields $x=0$ and $1-2x^{n}=0$ which yields $x=(1/2)^{1/n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{2}}$.
Hence the solutions are $x=0$ and $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{2}}$.

P.S. We are assuming that $n\not=0$.

Answer (score 2):

$$nx^{n-1}=2nx^{2n-1}$$
Either $n=0$, or,
$$x^{n-1}=2x^{2n-1}$$
Either $x=0$, or,
$$1=2x^n$$
$$x=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^\frac1n$$